# Magento 2.2.1 - Disable Add to Cart for Specific Products

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, addtocart, magento-2.2.1

I need to figure out a way to disable the "Add to Cart" button on specific products. I found [this link](https://magenticians.com/magento-2-disable-add-to-cart-button/), but it creates a full attribute set which I don't want to do. How can you add an attribute and make this feature work in the site?

Comment: If that product set to "out of stock", then magento it self not show add to cart button there.

Comment: Well, we do have an "Add To Quote" button. If I did this, it would remove this button too, right?

Comment: If you want to, then you need to overide addtocart.phtml like in link.

Comment: What code can I add in this file to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Create plugin for isSaleable method. Try following way to do that:

> **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="SR_MagentoStackExchange::add_to_cart" type="SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product" sortOrder="0"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Product
{
    public function afterIsSaleable(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($subject->getData('is_show_addtocart')) {
            return $result;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Create **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SR_MagentoStackExchange"/>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/registration.php**

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'SR_MagentoStackExchange', __DIR__);
```

After that run from command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: So after I create these two files, then what? Do I run anything in the command line? I've never created a plugin for Magento before and am new to the whole thing.

Comment: Create a new module and adjust my answer with your module.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how to do that either...

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, i have to create module.xml, registration.php, di.xml and product.php and run the setup:upgrade command in that order, right?

Comment: yes, that right.

Comment: I've created the files and directories, but I can't run the command line. It says "bin/magento must be run as a CLI application." Not sure what this means?